# C++ using a variable from an external file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++ but I like it so far.

Recently I have been making better and better builds of a console application that is just like a sign in thing, however you would give the password string and the username string in the same session.

I am trying to make it so that you open the application and checks for a certain file, and if it is not there it will create it and ask you to give it a value. I'm hoping this would make it so that I could have a user created password and username that is already set, rather than a couple of strings that already have a value but are not user created.

My code for my best version (its not great code) also not gonna post all of it just the part where they create the pass.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "iostream"
 #include "string"
 #include "windows.h"

 using namespace std;


 int main() {
     string user;
     string pass;
     string entry;

     cout << "Make your username\n";
     cin >> user;

     cout << "Make your password\n";
     cin >> pass;

     return 0;
     }
```

There is much more to this code (about 80 lines) but I don't feel like most of that information is needed.

Comment: [output file stream](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), [input file stream](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::ifstream` to manage the file

```
std::ifstream f("path_to_file");
if (f.fail()) {
    // we can't us the file (doesn't exist, incorrect permissions, etc.)
    // instead, ask the user to enter their credentials
} else {
    // read the file and extract necessary information
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This information is very helpful.